# ImportError: No module named mymodule.main

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, importerror, python-unittest

I have a test which requires instructions on how to run. The goal beyond working is to be noobproof, the instruction manual should consist of one command to run file, one to run the test. My friend said running unittests won't require files being on pythonpath because it checks current directory first, but I get:

```
import unittest

from ordoro_test.main import OrdoroETLMachine

class ETLMachineTests(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.api_url = 'https://9g9xhayrh5.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/test/data'
        self.headers = {'accept': 'application/json'}
        
    def test_data_is_returned(self):
        print(OrdoroETLMachine.get_email_data())
        
        
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

[image]

```
cchilders:~/ordoro_test [master]$ python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ordoro_test.main import OrdoroETLMachine
ImportError: No module named ordoro_test.main
cchilders:~/ordoro_test [master]$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cchilders cchilders    0 Mar  5 19:15 __init__.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cchilders cchilders 3099 Mar  5 20:12 main.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cchilders cchilders  441 Mar  5 20:19 test.py
```

How can I fix and allow imports the simplest way possible? Thank you

I try

```
from ordoro_test.assignment.main import OrdoroETLMachine
```

[image]

No dice

Answer (score 0):

Adding empty `__init__.py` file in one level with `ordoro_test`folder shall fix your problem.

See [Python 2.7, Modules section](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more information.

Comment: it is inside the ordoro_test folder, same level as the other 2 file

Comment: @codyc4321 add one more in one level with ordoro_test folder, not into it

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit relative import `from .main import OrdoroETLMachine`. [intra-package-references](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references)